# How do you remove text-decoration (underline) on the text in a Bootstrap Card when you make the card clickable?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I added an onClick function to the Card so you can go to the item detail view and read more and see more images. The onClick makes the text blue and gives it an underline. I overrode the blue text, but I cannot seem to remove the blue line when I hover.

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle, CardSubtitle } from 'reactstrap';
import './ItemCard.css';

class ItemCard extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
    <div>
      <Card className="text-center item-card" onClick={this.props.clicked} > 
        <CardImg top width="100%" src={this.props.image} alt="Card image cap" />
        <CardBody className="item-card-body">
          <CardTitle>{this.props.title}</CardTitle>
          <CardSubtitle>${this.props.price}</CardSubtitle>
          <CardText>{this.props.description}</CardText>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(ItemCard);
```

Component CSS:

```
.item-card {
  max-width: 20em;
  flex: 1;
  color: black;
}

.item-card :hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: please do not use !important for your own good :P

Comment: if you need to override some package styles, it's okay, but need to comment this place, to explain why you did that. In all other cases need to avoid `!important`

Comment: Was just trying something. I don't usually use it. It's gone now.

Answer (score 1):

`text-decoration` no inheritable property and you need to set it to child elements directly:

```
.item-card {
  max-width: 20em;
  flex: 1;
  color: black;
}

.item-card *:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. But if you mean adding a class to all of the children of `<Card>` and adding `text-decoration: none;`. It still doesn't work. I tried to add a class to `<CardTitle>` and `text-decoration: none;` as a test and nothing changed.

Comment: Try to reproduce your issue, but no luck. Probably you have some other styles which override this CSS?

Comment: I resolved the problem. The hyperlink was caused by Router Link in the component where I render the cards. I had to add some inline styles to the Link to override the text-decoration: `<Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}`